# If a POST call is sent and user kills browser before it's complete, does it finish?

Tags: api, rest, post

I'm unsure of the contract of a POST call connection. For example, a web page initiates a POST call and on the API side, the code begins executing. Say the code takes a couple minutes to complete, but the user closes the browser, severing the client side of the POST call.

Does this cause the API code to stop executing? If not, what happens when it tries to response to the web page, but the web page isn't there?

Comment: I imagine you could test this.  But I'm pretty sure the browser doesn't signal the server to cancel any operation.  Even if there is a means to do that in HTTP (which I'm not sure), there's never a guarantee that the browser is *going to* send it, nor have I ever seen an application which would meaningfully respond to it.  It's very, very likely that the code will simply continue to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the server receives the POST it starts executing it. It doesn't matter if the client closes the browser while the server is executing the POST.

When the server finishes the process and performs the response, it will sent to the client. Again, it doesn't matter if nobody receives it, it will try to send it.

**Note**: You can test the process with a proxy like Fiddler. Even if you close the browser you will see the server response.